# Strange logic with bool

Tags: python, boolean

I can't understand one thing with logic in python. Here is the code:

```
maxCounter = 1500
localCounter = 0

while True:
   print str(localCounter) + ' >= ' + str(maxCounter)
   print localCounter >= maxCounter

   if localCounter >= maxCounter:
      break

   localCounter += 30
```

And the result output:

```
...
1440 >= 1500
False
1470 >= 1500
False
1500 >= 1500
False
1530 >= 1500
False
1560 >= 1500
False
...
```

And I have infinity cycle there. Why?

---

```
topPos = someClass.get_element_pos('element')
scrolledHeight = 0

while True:
    print str(scrolledHeight) + ' >= ' + str(topPos)
    print scrolledHeight >= topPos
    if scrolledHeight >= topPos:
        print 'break'
        break

    someClass.run_javascript("window.scrollBy(0, 30)")
    scrolledHeight += 30
    print scrolledHeight

    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: Works for me. Check your indentation?

Comment: Are you sure you've posted the exact code you are running?  When I try it on Python 2.6 it works fine (I eventually see `1500 >= 1500` followed by `True` and then the program exits).

Comment: @kennytm I've upgraded my post. I don't have any another code there.

Comment: My guess is that you are comparing to a string instead of an integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix your code try this:

```
topPos = int(someClass.get_element_pos('element'))
```

**Why?**

When I copy and paste your original code I get this:

```
...
1440 >= 1500
False
1470 >= 1500
False
1500 >= 1500
True
```

One small change that I can find to make to your code that reproduces the behaviour you are seeing is to change the first line to this:

```
maxCounter = '1500'  # string instead of integer
```

After making this change I can also see the output you get:

```
1410 >= 1500
False
1440 >= 1500
False
1470 >= 1500
False
1500 >= 1500
False
1530 >= 1500
False
etc..
```

Comment: Yeah, I made such stupid error =( That was a string. Thank you.

Comment: Luckily in Python 3.x this source of errors has been fixed. Comparing a string to an integer will give an error: `TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()`

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be at this line:

```
topPos = someClass.get_element_pos('element')
```

This is likely to assign a string to `topPos`, instead of a numeric variable. You need to convert this string to a numeric variable so you can do a numeric comparison against it.

```
topPos = int(someClass.get_element_pos('element'))
```

Otherwise, e.g. in CPython implementation of v2.7, any `int` is always going to compare less than any string.

#### Related questions

- [How does Python compare string and int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270680/how-does-python-compare-string-and-int)

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Sorry, the another answer was posted earlier then youth.